# ¿Qué es realmente "throws"?

Tags: java

Estuve buscando por aquí a ver si había una pregunta parecida y solo me encontré una que no respondía del todo a la pregunta.

Voy directo al grano, ¿qué es y para que se utiliza el throws? He buscado por distintos lados y no me termina de quedar 100% claro que es. Lo que entiendo es que se utiliza en la declaración de un método para indicar que es probable que ocurra una excepción. No se si esto sea así realmente, además, si dicho método encuentra una excepción, el programa se deja de ejecutar o sigue de largo? No me queda del todo claro.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/throwing.html

Comment: El `throws` solo indica que el método puede lanzar `X` excepciones marcadas (excepciones que hereden de `Exception`) y esto es útil para el compilador, debido a que, puede darte información adicional sobre las excepciones que lanzaría el método.

Answer (score 4):

> Lo que entiendo es que se utiliza en la declaración de un método para indicar que es probable que ocurra una excepción.

Eso es correcto. `throws` indica que en ese método podría producirse una excepción y que esta será "lanzada" (  no capturada dentro del método)  para que sea atrapada en un nivel superior.

> si dicho método encuentra una excepción, el programa se deja de ejecutar o sigue de largo?

Eso depende.

Veamos el siguiente código:

```
    public class Test {

    public static void main(String... args) {
         Test t = new Test();
         t.metodo1();
    }

    public void metodo1() {
        try {
            metodo2();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    public void metodo2() throws Exception {
        throw new  Exception();
    }
}
```

En el código anterior, el `metodo2()` lanza una excepción `throw new  Exception();` En este punto el programa  no se ha detenido, simplemente se lanzó una excepción esperando que quien llamó a `metodo2()` atrape la excepción, en este caso es el `metodo1()` quien la atrapa en su `catch` y el programa sigue de largo.

**Siguiente caso:**

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String... args) {
         Test t = new Test();
        try {
            t.metodo1();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    public void metodo1() throws Exception {
       metodo2();
    }

    public void metodo2() throws Exception {

            throw new  Exception();
    }
}
```

Si el `metodo1()` no quiere atrapar la excepción entonces debe lanzarla para que quien llamó al `metodo1()` la atrape, por eso el `metodo1()` tiene un `throws Exception`. En este caso la excepción se atrapa en la función `main()` donde se llamó al `metodo1()`  y el programa sigue de largo.

**Siguiente caso:**

Si la función `main()` no quiere capturar la excepción debe lanzarla también de igual forma que lo hizo `metodo1()`. Pero en este caso, como la función `main()` es el punto de inicio del programa y ya no hay nada más arriba que atrape la excepción entonces el programa se detiene porque nada manejó la excepción.

Comment: Muy buena explicación @crrlos, solo un apunte: el `thows` solo tiene efecto sobre las excepciones de tipo **checked** que son las únicas que el lenguaje obliga a darle tratamineto en el método que la lanza

Comment: Por si a caso, las excepciones de tipo checked que menciona @E.Betanzos, son las que heredan de la clase [Exception](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html) (por ejemplo, [IOException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/IOException.html))